# No me captura el evento jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código para seleccionar una dirección con un glyphicon de bootstrap, pero, no me captura el evento.

```
            <td>
               <a href="#" class="selectpoblacion" data-  poblacion="@dir.DireccionEnvio">
               <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'> </span></a>
           </td>

           $('a .selectpoblacion', this).on('click', function (e) {
                e.PreventDefault()
                var prueba = (this).data("poblacion");
                console.log(prueba)
                $("#cambiar .close").click()//CERRAR MODAL
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba:

```
$('a.selectpoblacion').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

tienes un espacio dentro de la declaracion del selector.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un espacio de más en el atributo:

```
<a href="#" class="selectpoblacion" data-  poblacion="@dir.DireccionEnvio">
                                       ☝☝☝
```

Debería ser `data-poblacion`.

Comment: Por favor explica mejor esto. Tal como luce, parece un comentario.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza como estas?, cuentame que no entendistes de la respuesta?

Comment: Antes esta publicación lucía como un comentario. Luego de la edición de @Mariano, luce como una respuesta de calidad en el sitio. Te recomiendo revisar [el historial de revisiones de tu publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/40421/revisions) para que veas la diferencia entre la 1ra y la 2da versión de esta publicación.